# How to include one's affiliation within a text?

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-request

> Mr James, who works for BBC, has reported on this.

What else can we use in lieu of *who works for BBC*? How else can we express the same meaning?

Can we say *from BBC*? What is the most formal version?

Comment: Some wordings may sound more formal than others, but I don’t think there is any such thing as a “most formal version.”

Comment: In Britain, where **the BBC** is based, "BBC" is prefaced with a definite article. "The BBC is not responsible for the content of external sites."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can accomplish this quite simply by using a preposition like *of*:

> Mr James of BBC has reported on this.

Although I prefer *of*, I think *from* could also work:

> Mr James from BBC has reported on this.

We could also use *with*, especially if we supplied a bit more information about the person's role within the company:

> Mr James, a journalist with BBC, has reported on this.
>   Ms Ellison, an auditor with the IRS, has filed a compliant.

Other prepositions might be more fitting if the nature of the affiliation is something other than employment:

> Mr James, a contestant **on** *Wheel of Fortune*, has written a new book.
>   Mr James, a congressman **with** questionable ethics, is in hot water again.
>   Mr James, a resident **for** more than four years, passed away last night.

Prepositions are quite flexible and it’s therefore hard to recommend one that is always the right one to use.